# How to make Android Virtual Device access the internet?

Tags: android, networking

The internet is not available when I access it from the Android Virtual Device, any idea how can I configure it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean your app can't access the internet then you need the [Internet permission.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) If you mean that you can't access it by using the built-in browser or you have the permission enabled but are getting some error, then what is the error or exception log you are getting? There is nothing special that you need to do for the AVD to use the internet as long as your PC has a working internet connection.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but make sure that the AVD Software is not being blocked by a personal firewall program (e.g. ZoneAlarm).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your didn't press F8 and toggled it off.

```
Toggle cell networking on/off   F8
```

Comment: no, i didn't.. when I press it the 3G icon on the virtual device show/hide, I'm seeing, but it does not solve..